# why does the correct output still fair the test on CodeWars?

Tags: python, string, function

I am solving the following Codewars problem: https://www.codewars.com/kata/56dbe0e313c2f63be4000b25/train/python
there are a few examples are on the website too.

I have written the following code:

```
 def vert_mirror(str1):
     x = str1.split()
     temp_1 = []
     for i in x:
         temp_1.append(i[::-1])
         y = "\\n".join(temp_1)
     return print("'"+str(y)+"'")


 def hor_mirror(str1):
     x = str1.split()
     temp_2 = []
     for i in range(1, len(x) + 1):
         temp_2.append(x[(-i)])
         y = "\\n".join(temp_2)
     return print("'"+str(y)+"'")

 def oper(fct, s):
     if fct is vert_mirror:
         vert_mirror(s)
     elif fct is hor_mirror:
         hor_mirror(s)
```

Now, when you type this code into the website, and you test it for the vert_mirror test, you get the exact output that they expect, but for some reason the test fails? Any idea why?

I have tested it on my IDE and it seems to produce the right output, but for some reason when I run the test with the above code on the website it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following and it should work:

1. Change line `return print("'"+str(y)+"'")` to `return str(y)` . This does two things, in your code you are returning the return value of `print` function which is None, so instead of returning that we want to return a string. Second, you don't want to append `'` to the answer. Make this change in both the functions.
2. In your `oper` function add `return` keyword before `vert_mirror(s)` and `hor_mirror(s)`. Currently your `oper` function is not returning(explicitly) anything, which leads to the default return value of None(the default return value of a function in python).
3. Change `\\n` to `\n`.

This will pass the tests.

Feel free to accept this as answer if it helps.